# How to get constant size of vector for an array declaration?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I am reading the data from text file which is basically has rows and columns of double data types.
Part of the code is as shown below:

```
   m_data = vector<vector<double> >(columns, vector<double>(lineCount - 3));
        for (int x = 0; x < lineCount - 3; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < columns; y++)
            {
                m_data[y][x] = total_Data[it]; //total_Data is the complete data set read from a file 
                it++;                        //which contain all data sets from a simulation and they are 
                                            //separated into vectors here in this code

            }
        }
   size_t len = m_data[1].size();     //m_data[1] vector represents the signal data set
   double signaldata[len];
   copy(m_data[1].begin,m_data[1].end,signaldata);
```

So the problem is when I copy the data from vector to array it requires the constant length of the array for initialization. But size() gives the length of the vector which is not a constant.
And sizeof(vector) returns the size of the object itself which is 16 bytes.
So how I can overcome this problem of getting a constant size from vector for array initialization

Comment: Why `copy(m_data[1].begin,m_data[1].end,signaldata);` and not `copy(m_data[0].begin,m_data[0].end,signaldata);`?

Comment: You can't allocated statically array with variable. You should allocate it dinamically, like double* signaldata = new double[len]

Comment: signal data set is present in vector positioned at 1 :) @BlueTune

Comment: `double signaldata[len];` is invalid C++, as it uses VLA extension.

Comment: okay I have another question for this solution.So if suppose I go for dynamic creation of array   like :        double* signaldata = new double[len]  ; can I assign it to another constant variable pointer like :         const double *data = signaldata;      does this work out??  @armagedescu

Comment: You already have `vector`, not why use it?

Comment: cuz I am using some library so I need to match their declarations and their data structures@Jarod42

Comment: @pod `vector<T>::data` will return `&vector[0]`

Comment: u mean instead of creating a new array I can directly assign it like this : const double * data = m_data[1]::data  some like this concept??  sorry there may be syntax and error @LonesomeParadise

Comment: @pod use vector.data() if you need the array. Ok, I suggest to use vector first.

Comment: thanks alot,  does it mean const double *data = m_data[1].data(); right?? @armagedescu

Comment: @pod yes, only you should check the correct life cycle of buffer. It should not get destroyed before it is used.

Comment: so exactly how can I ensure that please? @armagedescu unless the function returns after computations from its end I am not reassigning or deleting the vector

Comment: @pod Check the answer. It is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: You can't.

An `std::vector` is designed to have dynamic size, that is its size can change at runtime (i.e by loop from user input). In C++ it is not legal to create an 'array' of a non-compile time constant size. You *can* however create a dynamically allocated 'array' with `new` (e.g `auto my_array = new char[vector.size()]`). You *really* should not do this however, *especially* without doing any sanity checks on the size of the vector.

An alternative would be to use `std::vector` directly. If you have to work with an older (or C) API which requires a pointer to the beginning of your 'array' as an argument you can use `vector::<T>::data` which will return `&vector[0]`.

So if I have this code:

```cpp
void my_old_api_function(char* c) {
...
}
```

I can do this:

```cpp
std::vector<char> my_data;
my_data.emplace_back('c');
...
my_old_api_function(my_data.data()); // Pass a pointer to the first element
```